# Clojure: Finding the highest first element of a second element of a tuple and returning the first element of the found tuple

Tags: clojure

Finding the highest first element of a second element of a tuple and returning the first element of the found tuple.

```
(defn test [cards]
                                        
  (->>
   (apply max (map #(get % 1) cards))
   (.indexOf (map #(get % 1) cards) )
   (get cards)
   (first)
   )
  )

(test [[1 14] [3 24] [2 12] [4 24])
```

=> 3

This works perfectly, but is there a more idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: If it weren't for the first one, i'd suggested `(->> cards (apply max-key second) (first))`

Comment: @cfrick Looks elegant, i could reverse the list first and the solution would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

A very basic way, using `reduce` and [destructuring](https://clojure.org/guides/destructuring):

```
(->> cards
     (reduce (fn [[_ v0 :as t0] [_ v :as t]]
                 (if (> v v0) t t0)))
     first)
```